# what does nodeJS express timeout actually do?

Tags: node.js, express

I was recently refactoring some code and came across this piece of code in `server.js`.

I looked out for the docs and I still have some unanswered questions.

```
const server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});

server.timeout = 600000   // 6 mins.
```

What is `server.timeout` actually doing above? If the response has to time out in 6 minutes, how is my download API still working? Each download takes more than 10 minutes to download. Also, I send a response back to the client after download is complete.

Comment: [`app.listen()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) and [`server.timeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`express` docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen):

> The `app.listen()` method returns an [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) object

From the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout):

> The number of milliseconds **of inactivity** before a socket is presumed to have timed out.

<sup>emphasis added</sup>

This means that if there's an actively streaming download, this property will not apply. It only applies to sockets where ACKs are not received by the client for 6 minutes.